# Ajax livecount is not in a comma format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How can I show my count in comma form? Currently, even tho it is in thousand form, it is not doing a comma. Is there any way how can I make it work? Thank you in advance. I provided the codes below and the screenshot of my current problem + my target. Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
//// I do show my live count by triggering the id="countBalance" from my ajax script

    <h3 id="countBalance"><sup style="font-size: 20px"> Php</sup></h3>
```

**Ajax:**

```
<script>
function liveBalance(){

  $.ajax({          
            url:'<?=site_url('masteragent/liveBalance')?>',
             type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
            $('#countBalance').html(data);
 
            }
      });





}
setInterval(function(){ 
liveBalance() 
},1000);

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
function liveBalance(){
    
    
    
    $output=$this->masters->live_balance();
    
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Model:

```
 function live_balance(){
        
        $reqamount= $this->session->userdata('uid');
        
        $this->db->select('balance');
        $this->db->where('maID',$reqamount);
        
        $result = $this->db->get('prefunding_ma')->row();
        
        return $result->balance;
    }
```

Comment: use Numbers [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method

Answer (score 1):

Dear in your controller change

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

to

```
echo json_encode(number_format($output));
```

Comment: Wow, works perfectly. I didn't know that it was so simple. I only know the echo number format in PHP, but not in ajax/script. Thank you for this. Super appreciated.